# Is it wrong to think of area as a measure of the total number of points?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following mapping $f: M \to N$ between the points on a hemisphere and the points on a circle of radius r, illustrated by the figure below

[image]

Clearly this is a bijection between the two sets, and also if I'm not mistaken, a homeomorphism. Every point on the circle corresponds to a point on the hemisphere and vice versa, and yet one has double the area of the other. How is this possible? How is area rigorously defined in higher mathematics, so as to make sense of this?

Comment: A segment and a square have the same "amount" of points.... so the answer to your question is YES, IT IS WRONG. Be careful with infinity.

Comment: You cut the surface up into little "rectangles", add up their areas, and take a limit as the dimensions of the "rectangles" go to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about area in any book about measure theory. It's called the $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Homeomorphisms are too strong to preserve area in any reasonable way. What you want to look at is linear maps, differentiable maps, or in even more generality, Lipschitz maps, the last one appearing in geometric measure theory. Then you get formulas for area *in terms of those maps and the original set.*

In general, translations and rotations preserve area completely, which are pretty rigid geometric notions.

Comment: Well, to define the measure of the hemisphere you need more than the Lebesgue measure. I think you need Riemannian Differential geometry.

Comment: @filippo there's something called the $2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You don't need the theory of differentiable manifolds to define it. I think you need it to give explicit formulas, but that too can be circumvented.

Comment: Yes, that's an alternative. My point was that the Lebesgue measure is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it wrong to think of area as a measure of the total number of points?

Yes. These concepts are very vaguely related. Especially when infinities are in play.

> Clearly this is a bijection between the two sets, and also if I'm not mistaken, a homeomorphism. Every point on the circle corresponds to a point on the hemisphere and vice versa, and yet one has double the area of the other. How is this possible?

Well, homeomorphisms don't have to preserve area. A simpler example is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $f(v)=\frac{1}{2}v$ which is a homeomorphism as well, but it doesn't preserve area. For example $f([0,1]^2)=[0,\frac{1}{2}]^2$ and so the image has $4$ times smaller area.

Infinities are weird indeed. This is something you have to accept.

> How is area rigorously defined in higher mathematics, so as to make sense of this?

This is done via so called measure theory. You first need a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) on which so called [measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) are defined. Then we define [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) which is a measure of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This measure is tightly related to dimension, and so it won't give you correct answer when trying to calculate "area" ($2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure) of subsets of $3$-dimensional space, like your hemisphere (its Lebesgue measure is simply $0$). But it is important, because it is a building block for other measures.

In the case of a surface this can be done by approximating it with simpler shapes. First you [triangulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)) the surface, meaning you divide it into "triangles". Not real triangles, but "curved" triangles. Meaning each triangle on the surface is simply a set of three points. Now you calculate the area of each triangle. You simply treat them like normal triangles, you ignore the fact that they are curved. This of course won't give you the correct result. But by making the triangulation denser and denser you will get a better and better approximation each time. By going to infinity (taking a limit) you will get the real area.

Of course if you try to do this by hand you will quickly realize that this kind of calculations is not for humans. It is too hard. That's where measure theory helps. It reduces the problem to calculating appropriate integrals.

This method of triangulation can be applied to many different shapes, but not all subsets can be triangulated. For those other subsets, you will need more sophisticated tools. I encourage you to learn the measure theory first.